# How can I get aligned equations not to be spoiled by an item?

Tags: lists, align

Is it possible to use `itemize` between align? For instance one wants to list some equations with previous explanations following an `item`, but one wants the explanations not to break the align structure, so that, say, the equal signs are aligned? What I want is:

[image]

My attempts to interlace an item in an  give an error.

In this MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \begin{itemize}
 \item This is the expansion for $f$:
\begin{align}
f(X) = & \sum_n {t_n+x_n-s_n-2} X^n 
 \end{align}
 \item This is the expansion for $g$:
 \begin{align}
g(X) = & \sum_m {r_m} X^m  
 \end{align}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I get the equations unaligned.

Comment: There's no need for the two equal signs to be aligned in this case. Just use `equation`.

Comment: btw, you should use `&=` instead of `=&` in `align` constructions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `\intertext` command for`align` for any text you wish to have between aligned equations. i.e. your MWE would become:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \begin{itemize}
 \item This is the expansion for $f$:
 \begin{align}
   f(X) &= \sum_n {t_n+x_n-s_n-2} X^n 
 \intertext{\item This is the expansion for $g$:}
   g(X) &= \sum_m {r_m} X^m  
 \end{align}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

As mentioned by @tohecz it is conventional to use `&=` not `=&`

Comment: Please, correct for the OP the position of `&`: the proper way is `&=` rather than `=&`.

Comment: @TomBrien -- the reason for the relative positions of `&=` is stronger than mere convention: if the `&` is put after the operator, the spacing is wrong.

Comment: @barbarabeeton just tested this and your right. I've always done it the 'correct' way so never noticed.